# Redim'd array error in commodore 64 basic?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, basic, commodore

I am getting a redim'd array error in my commodore 64 basic project

I am not however re dimensioning my 2d array nor do I go through the line of code more than once!

Error is on line 1140

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Code:

```
10 print "start"
20 rem: go to line 1100 in order to fill board with "."s because this is
30 rem: the board's initialization
40 gosub 1100
50 rem: looping from i to x allows for horizontal aspect of board to be printed
60 rem: x represents the width dimension of board, in this case, 8
70 for i = 1 to x
80 rem: looping from j to x allows for vertical aspect of board to be printed
90 rem: x represents the height dimension of board, in this case, 8
100 for j = 1 to x
110 rem: board initialized with "."s is printed
120 print b3$(i,j), 
130 rem: end of first for loop, looping from i to x put on 130; , USED 4 TAB
140 next
150 print
160 rem: end of second for loop, looping from j to x
170 next
180 rem: checks what at the random number is equal to; places word vertically
190 rem: if rand is < 50 and places the word horizontally if rand is > 50
200 if r1 < 50 then gosub 1510
210 if r1 > 50 then print "no"

1000 rem: random num generator generates a random integer
1050 rem: between 0 and 100
1040 rem: values between 0 and 100, inclusive
1050 r1 = int(100*rnd(1))+1


1060 rem: Subroutine Fill 
1070 rem: Purpose: read and data construct which fills b3$(x,x) with
1080 rem: either "."s or other random words depending on whether or not
1090 rem: the subroutine has been run before.
1100 x = 8
1110 rem: x represents the dimension for the board; in this case,8
1120 rem: took out 
1130 rem: array b3 = board = specifications for width and height (8)
1140 dim b3$(x, x)
rem: i to x allows the horizontal aspect of board to be filled with "."s
1150 for i = 0 to x 
1160 rem: j to x allows the vertical aspect of board to be filled with "."s
1170 for j = 0 to x
1180 rem: board filled with dots horizontally and vertically
1190 b3$(i, j) = "."
1200 rem: end of first nested for loop
1210 next
1220 rem: end of second nested for loop
1230 next
1240 return
```

Answer (score 6):

You need an `end` statement before your subroutines. To make sure you don't interfere with anything else, something like:

```
1099 end
```

Otherwise, your program "completes," and then runs through all your subroutine code again just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the line `rem: i to x allows the horizontal aspect of board to be filled with "."s` after the 1140 line doesn't have any number. To solve the problem, you can remove the line or put the number 1145 (for example) before.

Comment: that's just a comment though?

Answer (score -1):

Line 200 looks suspect, because line 1510 doesn't exist.

```
200 if r1 < 50 then gosub 1510
```